# could not access azure mysql

Tags: mysql, azure, tomcat

I have a MySQL server database running on Azure. It has already running to store data from my ASPX web apps hosted on Azure also. I have plan to migrate the apps to Java JSF or .net core.
I developed using Tomcat server (in my local pc) and try to connect directly to mySql in Azure. But I always get Communications link failure error.
Is it not allow to connect directly from my local Tomcat server to database in Azure, or something else?
Thank you in advance for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can connect from your local tomcat to your azure mysql if you have provided the correct connection string.

Also add your **`ip`** in the **`firewall`** rules of the sql resource.